# Error while exporting to PDF function parameter in Excel only in office computer

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, excel

I have a program which do total process in Excel using VS2010. In the last, the output format I have changed as pdf from Excel using `exportfixedformat`.

It works well in the my computer, but not in my office computer. It showing following error at the following statement:

```
oWs.ExportAsFixedFormat( _
        Excel.XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, _
        fpath & "\" & "12345.pdf", _
        Excel.XlFixedFormatQuality.xlQualityStandard, _
        True, _
        True, _
        1, _
        10, _
        False)
```

Kinldy guide me?

Comment: Different Excel versions?

Comment: I think it is the `fpath`parameter being changed when running on another machine . Try to set an absolute path.

Comment: Different Windows versions?

Comment: Cultural differences? (System language different?)

Comment: maybe your CAPS-LOCK is broken? ;)

Comment: In both places same versions of Excel and Windows. fpath is the parameter which is assigned using Opendialog command

Comment: anyone have any idea how it went wrong?

Comment: The error details are:

Comment: finally i got it  An error will occur if the PDF add-in is not currently installed.